# NLTK error in running program with Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, nltk, hadoop-streaming, wordnet

I have an error when I run a program with Hadoop streaming , the cause of this error is from the library NLTK , I made a simple test and I got error

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn 
if(wn.synsets('dog')):
     print 'something'
```

but if I run this program in my local not with Hadoop Streaming it run without any problem.

NB : I want to use this code in my Map/reduce program.

Here is the trace of the error :

```
18/01/04 06:26:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1515067732811_0013 running in uber mode : false
18/01/04 06:26:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/01/04 06:27:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
18/01/04 06:27:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/01/04 06:27:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1515067732811_0013_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
```

```
18/01/04 06:27:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1515067732811_0013_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

18/01/04 06:27:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1515067732811_0013_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

18/01/04 06:27:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1515067732811_0013_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Comment: Please let us know what the error was

Comment: I added the error in post , please if you have any idea about that , let me know please ..Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As for using hadoop streaming, most probably you need to have a mapper and reducer separately like http://www.datacommunitydc.org/blog/2013/05/nltk-hadoop

Comment: Yes, I have the 2 files separately , and the nltk code is in the reducer , so the mapper pass successfully , but the problem is on the reducer where is the nltk code